# Removing redundant JUnit testsuite tests

Tags: java, junit, performance

In our JUnit testsuite, I have spotted a few tests that do not drive up coverage, and thus should be removed (they take time but does not really add value to the test suite).

I was wondering what tools exist that can spot redundant tests for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd consider this a misuse of the code coverage metric. Just because a test doesn't increase the metric, it is not necessarily redundant - it could test a specific execution path that consists of LOC that are covered by several other tests together, but represents behaviour that none of the other tests cover. And remember: code behaviour is influenced very much by state, but no test coverage tool I know measures the coverage of state space.

Unless the runtime of your test suite is a serious problem, there are much better things you can do with your time than eliminate possibly redundant tests.

Comment: I tend to agree with you (may be misuse of coverage metric). But there are other metrics as well, so I think this problem should be approached wider and look at more of the standard metrics, like for instance also number of conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

Some months ago I used Eclipse plugin [**Clover**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/atlassian-clover-eclipse). It could show how many times each line of code be executed and highlight after unit tests. I think Clover could help you at this point.

Comment: That is not really my point here:) I use Cobertura on Hudson and IntelliJ's own coverage tool during development. The latter also shows the number of times each line passes. But not from which tests! I want to know which tests that do not add to better coverage, and since I am not autistic, I cannot myself remember how many times the test suite passes each line in my codebase.

Comment: Understood. I hope Clover added the very new feature during these months:)